# how to control rich:modalpanel header scrolling

Tags: css

Im using `Richfaces 3.3.3` in my page i am using `rich:modalpanel` for show log details inside the modalpanel and also i am using scroll option for this modalpanel.whenever i scroll vertically 
   or horizontally then the content which is inside the modal panel will also scrolling.but 
   the same time modal panel header also scrolling. if i use HTML div element for scrolling 
   then if change modal panel size after that  its only resized div element not get resize

```
  following code will explain clearly,

<rich:modalPanel id="logModalPanel"                  
                 width="800"                                          
                 resizeable="true" 
                 style="height:600px;overflow:scroll;">  

                  <f:facet name="header" >
                  <h:outputText  id="ModalPanelHeader" 
                  value="#{bean.logFileName}" />
                  </f:facet>

               <f:facet name="controls">
                  <h:graphicImage id="modalPanelCloseIcon" 
                  value="#{..///closeImage}"
                  onclick="#{rich:component('logModalPanel')}.hide();">
                  </h:graphicImage>
               </f:facet>

               <h:form>
               <rich:panel id="logDetailsPanel" 
                  styleClass="remove-border" 
                  style=" width:100%; height:100%;">

                <div >   
                <pre>${bean.content}</pre>
                </div>

           </rich:panel>
           </h:form>
          </rich:modalPanel>
```

if i move scroll bar as horizintally then header tag will also moved as horizontally and close image as come on center point of modal panel.then if i move vertically facet header also moved. 
how can i fix it?